# CONFLUENCE: How to get page id displaying by my plugin

Tags: plugins, confluence

i have a small problem, i would like to get an id of displaying page in my plugin (id of searchskills.vm).

```
<xwork ... >
...
<action name="searchskills"  class="de.twt.confluence.plugins.actions.SearchSkillsAction">
      <result name="success" type="velocity">/templates/manager/searchskills.vm</result>
</action>
...
</xwork>
```

but i can't get it form:

```
page = getWebInterfaceContext().getPage();
```

it returns only null!!!

Is there a way to get a page id?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [Show page ID](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DISC/Show+the+content+ID+%28page+ID%29+in+a+page) I'm not sure if that's the solution you are looking for, could you give us a more detailed description of what you're trying to do?